# RecyclerView gravity to chat message

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I'm developing a chat app, but I can't figure out how to adjust the messages (gravity) based on the user sent/receiver.

What I've tried:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MessageDialogViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final QBChatMessage item = messageList.get(position);
        holder.attachEntity(item);
        holder.text.setText(item.getBody());
        holder.personName.setText(ChatService.getInstance().getDialogsUsers().get(item.getSenderId()).getFullName());

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        if(item.getSenderId().equals(ChatService.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getId())){
            params.gravity = Gravity.END;
            holder.container.setGravity(Gravity.END);
        }else{
            params.gravity = Gravity.START;
            holder.container.setGravity(Gravity.START);
        }

        holder.container.setLayoutParams(params);

    }
```

My xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/singleMessageContainer"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bubble_b"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgMessage"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/personName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/singleMessage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

What am I missing here ?

Thanks for your time, any help is appreciated !

Comment: no. you should set gravity of children.

Comment: I don't see how this is going to resolve my problem.

Comment: Look my code . It has nothing with parent's gravity .

Answer (score 2):

Here's my working code:

```
public class MessageLentItem extends LinearLayout {

    public MessageLentItem(Context context, String textMessage, boolean fromMe) {
        super(context);
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.message_lent_item, this);

        LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
        LinearLayout messageLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.messageLayout);
        TextView messageText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.messageText);

        messageText.setText(textMessage);
        if (fromMe) {
            mainLayout.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
            messageText.setPadding(10, 5, 20, 5);
            messageLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.balloon_outgoing_normal);
        } else {
            mainLayout.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
            messageText.setPadding(20, 5, 10, 5);
            messageLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.balloon_incoming_normal);
        }
    }
```

just replace `Linearlayout` to `Relative` in your xml

Comment: Do I really need to override LinearLayout just to set a gravity at runtime ?

Comment: No, it's just an example.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Set `LinearLayout` to `macth_parent`.

Set each childView's `layout gravity`.

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LinearLayout.layoutParams)holder.personName.getLayoutParams();

lp.gravity = Gravity.LEFT or lp.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;

holder.personName.setLayoutParams(lp)


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/singleMessageContainer"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:id="@+id/imgMessage"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:visibility="visible"/>

    <TextView
        android:text="left"
        android:id="@+id/personName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        />

    <TextView

        android:id="@+id/singleMessage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:text="left"
        android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light"/>


    <ImageView
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:id="@+id/imgMessage1"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:visibility="visible"/>

    <TextView
        android:text="left"
        android:id="@+id/personName1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        />

    <TextView

        android:id="@+id/singleMessag1e"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:text="left"
        android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: When you change  android:layout_gravity="start" to  android:layout_gravity="end" .there is no change in you preview?

Comment: LinearLayout 's android:layout_width="wrap_content"  to android:layout_width="macth_parent" .

Comment: Doing the layout change, the balloon gets shown on the entire screen.

Comment: I'd like a behaviour similar to whatsApp, the ballon wraping the content and on each side

Comment: I haven't used whatsApp .Can you provide a  screenshot?

Comment: I'm going to sleep.Bye.

Comment: http://www.pandasecurity.com/mediacenter/src/uploads/2014/11/blue-double-check-whatsapp.jpg Thank you !

Comment: It just have one text.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95603/discussion-between-leonardo-ferrari-and-tiny-sunlight).

Comment: If you want to get a stroke around text.just set a maxwidth to textview ,add a 9patch bubble background,add set padding of it

Comment: Just add a linearlayout with maxwith in the linerlaout to contain 3childview

Answer (score 0):

just change your layout file to this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/singleMessageContainer"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/bubble_b"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgMessage"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:visibility="gone"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/personName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/singleMessage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:layout_margin="5dip"
    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
    android:text=""
    android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light"/>
```

Just replaced 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
with "match_parent"

Hope that works.

Answer (score 0):

Try it
new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow.  Sounds like it might be a great idea - perhaps you can post a bit more of a code snippet showing how to get what the OP was after?

Answer (score -1):

*This must be a comment, not an aswer but I haven't enought reputation points*

I would put a Log.d() message:

```
    }else{
        params.gravity = Gravity.START;
        holder.container.setGravity(Gravity.START);
    }

    Log.d(TAG, params.gravity + item.getSenderID());

    holder.container.setLayoutParams(params);
```

to see if '=' inside if-else is working good.

Also, I would try with RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout, and change layout_gravity of elements inside with layout_alignParentStart, layout_alignParentEnd, etc.

Comment: Fortunately, this isn't actually a comment. But in the future, please do not attempt to work around the commenting restrictions by posting answers -- that just means more work for those who have to delete them.